# Reference to configuration manager via httpcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, configurationmanager

How can i get reference to the configuration manager via httpcontext?

Thanks

Comment: why via httpcontext? All you need is a using System.Configuration; and you can reference it directly ex. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""]`

Comment: @Learing; Please provide details why you need this ?

Comment: This is not used inside a controller or base controller. I have a utility service class that has some common methods. This class is in separate project than the web site.

Comment: @shiznit123 - thanks for pointing me into right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Adam, use:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

It doesn't matter if it is in a class in a separate project.  When you call the code from your web project, the ConfigurationManager will logic will be applied to your web app, not the containing project.

Answer (score 0):

simply: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""] 
(of course with a using stmt up top for System.Configuration - and make sure your library has a ref to system.configuration)